# Can't decrypt file encrypted using openssl AES_ctr128_encrypt

Tags: java, openssl, aes

I have a file encrypted using the following code in c:

```
unsigned char ckey[] =  "0123456789ABCDEF"; 
unsigned char iv[8] = {0};
AES_set_encrypt_key(ckey, 128, &key);
AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, 16, &key, aesstate.ivec, aesstate.ecount, &aesstate.num);
```

I have to decrypt this file using java so I was using the code below to do it:

```
private static final byte[] encryptionKey = new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

byte[] iv = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey, "AES");
aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec, ips);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(in);
CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out), aesCipher);       
copy(is, os);       
os.close();
```

The JAVA code doesn't give me any error but the output is not correct.

What am I doing wrong?

My main doubts are if i'm using the correct padding (also tried PKCS5Padding without success) and if the key and iv are correct (don't know what the function AES_set_encrypt_key really does...).

** EDIT **

I think I have an answer to my own question, but I still have some doubts.

CTR means counter mode. The function AES_ctr128_encrypt receives as parameters the actual counter (ecount) and the number of blocks used (num).

The file is being encrypted in blocks of 16 bytes, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i+=16)
{
   // .. buffer processing here
   init_ctr(&aesstate, iv); //Counter call
   AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, 16, &key, aesstate.ivec, aesstate.ecount, &aesstate.num);
}
```

the function init_ctr does this:

```
int init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[8])
{
    state->num = 0;
    memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);
    memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);
    memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

This means that before every encryption/decryption the C code is resetting the counter and the ivec.

I am trying to decrypt the file as a whole in java. This probably means Java is using the counter correctly but the C code is not as it is resetting the counter at each block.

Is my investigation correct?

I have absolutely NO CONTROL over the C code that is calling openssl. Is there a way of doing the same in JAVA, i.e. resetting the counter at each block of 16? (The API only requests the key, algorithm, mode and IV)

My only other option is to use openssl via JNI but I was trying to avoid it...

Thank you!

Comment: Just a note: You can write your initialization vector shorter as `byte[] iv = new byte[16]`. Shouldn't this have the same length in C and Java? (Or are you even using it in your C code?)

Comment: Thank you Paulo. The IV that is used is ivec, which is an extension of the iv declared (done in init_ctr). In the end, for this example, it will have 16 byte length as well, being all zeros.

Comment: Ouch. This is effectively using a CTR function to emulate ECB mode. Please hit whomever wrote this C program.

Comment: (In fact, not emulating ECB, but emulating a caesar cipher on a 128-bit alphabet. See my answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not try it, but you should be able to effectively emulate what is done there on the C side - decrypt each 16-byte (=128 bit) block separately, and reset the cipher between two calls.

---

Please note that using CTR mode for just one block, with a zero initialization vector and counter, defeats the goal of CTR mode - **it is worse than [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29)**.

If I see this right, you could try to encrypt some blocks of zeros with your C function (or the equivalent Java version) - these should come out as the same block each time. XOR this block with any ciphertext to get your plaintext back.

This is the equivalent to a  Caesar cipher on a 128-bit alphabet (e.g. the 16-byte blocks), the block cipher adds no security here to a **simple 128-bit XOR cipher**. Guessing one block of plaintext (or more generally, guessing 128 bits at the right positions, not necessary all in the same block) allows getting the effective key, which allows getting all the remaining plaintext blocks.

Comment: Paulo, you are absolutely right. I haven't tested it yet but the way the C code is doing the cipher is completely wrong. I will try to see what i can do on both ends to guarentee the integration but i want definately this to be AES and not some sort of caeser cipher.

Comment: Just to add, the answer from SLaks is also true, there were 2 problems: the wrong key and the wrong way of encrypting the file.

Answer (score 2):

Your encryption keys are different.

The C code uses the ASCII character codes for `0` through `F`, whereas the Javacode uses the actual bytes `0` through `16`.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of my doubts, but 
unsigned char ckey[] =  "0123456789ABCDEF";  

ported to java shouldn't be 

new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

?

what should be the correct porting?

Comment: Bytes aren't characters. You need to convert the characters to their ASCII values.  For example, `'0'` is `0x30`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and see how it goes

Comment: made that change, the key would be {48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70} in JAVA but the file is still not correctly decrypted :( any other idea? There's probably something else i'm doing wrong as well...

Comment: No idea.  Try looking at all relevant values in the debuggers.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous serious problems with that C code:

- As already noted, it is reinitialising the counter on every block.  This makes the encryption completely insecure.  This can be fixed by calling `init_ctr()` once only, prior to encrypting the first block.
- It is setting the IV statically to zero.  A fresh IV should be generated randomly, for example `if (!RAND_bytes(iv, 8)) { /* handle error */ }`.
- The code appears to be directly using a password string as the key.  Instead, a key should be generated from the password using a key derivation function like PBKDF2 (implemented in OpenSSL by `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1()`).